# How can i set default value for many2many fields

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I need to copy many2many field content to another default field' many2many field in invoices_line_tax_id

```
for rep in ex.repartition_line_ids:
                obj = self.env['account.analytic.default']
                obj_id = obj.search([('product_id','=',rep.product_id.id)])
                for o in obj_id:
                    if o.product_id.id == rep.product_id.id:
                        a = o.analytic_id.id
                new_line1 = (0, 0, {'product_id': rep.product_id.id,
                                    'name': rep.expedition_id.name,
                                    'account_id':rep.product_id.property_account_expense.id,
                                    'account_analytic_id':a,
                                    'invoice_tax_line_id':[(6,0,rep.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.id)],
                                    'quantity': 1,
                                    'price_unit': rep.montant
                                    })
                new_lines1.append(new_line1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many2many in the view deals only with Ids only, if you notice when 
you add an element you eather select one that exist or
you create a new one, I repeat you create a new in the database.
I don't know what you want here but I think you looking for a one2many
relation not a many2many relation.

so what you need is first create the record in the database then add
its id to command list.

here is the solution but I really don't recommand that at all:

```py
   # always put this at the top outside of the loop 
   # to be executed only one time
   object_2 = self.env['model_of_man2many_field']
   obj = self.env['account.analytic.default']

   for rep in ex.repartition_line_ids:         
            obj_id = obj.search([('product_id','=',rep.product_id.id)])
            a = False  # and this to make sure you are safe if you didn't find analytic_id
            for o in obj_id:
                if o.product_id.id == rep.product_id.id:
                    a = o.analytic_id  and o.analytic_id.id or False
                    # I think you forget break here
                    if a:
                        break

            rec = object_2.create({'product_id': rep.product_id.id,
                                'name': rep.expedition_id.name,
                                'account_id':rep.product_id.property_account_expense.id,
                                'account_analytic_id':a,
                                'invoice_tax_line_id':[(6,0,rep.product_id.supplier_taxes_id.id)],
                                'quantity': 1,
                                'price_unit': rep.montant
                                })
            new_lines1.append(rec.id)

    # and finaly
    return [(6, 0, new_lines1)]
```

but I think what you need is to search for existing record don't you think? because the diffrenece
here is that you will create a lot of record each time you hit create button even if you hit cancel.